# Show you've already voted to delete a post in the 10K tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

In the [10K tools "Delete votes" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days), posts that you cannot vote to delete/undelete are grayed out but shown for the sake of consistency.  I'd like it if there were something similar for posts you've *already* voted to delete.  Often I click on a question that has 2 delete votes, decide if I should del-vote, and then find I've already voted to delete it.

So, can we add something to indicate that you've already voted to delete a post from that page?  Maybe just gray it out, but change the tooltip to "You have already voted to delete this post"?  This should also apply to posts you've already voted to *close*.

Comment: Perhaps you could request some extra memory modules for yourself, to remember which posts you voted on ;)

Comment: Same with "Close votes"

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' That's a good point, I'll edit that in.

Comment: Note that one can _mitigate_ this by mousing over the "Delete" link to see if you've already voted, a feature I just discovered today.  Of course, for those who use the tools page to find delete-worthy questions, this still requires navigating off that page to check if you've voted.